# Implementing Simplesamlphp in drupal 7 site. can not able to view simplesaml page. its loading folder structure

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

Implementing Simplesamlphp in Drupal 7 site. Downloaded simplesamlphp folder and placed on.

Added below lines in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName firstwebsite.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/firstwebsite.com"
    SetEnv SIMPLESAMLPHP_CONFIG_DIR "C:/xampp/htdocs/simplesamlphp/config"
    Alias /simplesaml "C:/xampp/htdocs/simplesamlphp/public"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/simplesamlphp/public">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Next add  'baseurlpath' => 'http://firstwebsite.com/simplesaml', in below file
C:\xampp\htdocs\simplesamlphp\config\config.php.dist

Did all necessary changes in this config file.

Restarted Apache.

While hitting http://firstwebsite.com/simplesaml this is getting folder structure.

I cant find where and what i missed.

Using Drupal 7,
Windows 7

How to configure Nginx for this setup.